# One line for "background" properties

Tags: css, background

How i can transform this:

```
background-color: #f0f0f0;
background-image: url(../img/file.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 30px;
background-position: left;
```

on some thing like this, :

```
background : blablalbal blalbalalba balblablala
```

Is it possible? In order, how look like?

Answer (score 3):

It is bit easy

```
.foo {
  background: bg-color bg-image position/bg-size bg-repeat bg-origin bg-clip bg-attachment initial|inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible you can write like this

background:url("../img/file.png") no-repeat scroll left 30px #f0f0f0;

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do it on two lines :

background: #AAAAAA url() repeat-x repeat-y attachement position-x position-y;

Background-size:30px;